# How do I get a string from the terminal in Ruby after a certain amount of time?

Tags: ruby, gets

Im trying to create a command line program which asks the user for an input, but only gets the string after a certain time (example: 5 seconds).

Im currently using gets.chomp, however this requires a return.

Anyone know of any useful methods?

Comment: You could put in sleep(5) before the gets.chomp and that might accomplish what you are trying to do. It would still require a return, though.

Comment: Yeah really i want to sleep for 5 seconds then get whatever is in the command line, without a return

Comment: Sorry, that'd probably require some asynchronous/multi-threaded code. It's a major nightmare to do that... Can I ask what the context is, what are you trying to achieve with this behaviour?

Comment: Building a game where the user has to answer a series of questions. Im trying to increase difficulty by adding a limit to the time they have to answer each question

Comment: Would it be sufficient to just tell them "you took too long" when they hit return after six seconds?

Comment: If you tell the user they have 5 seconds to answer and press return, you could set `end_time = Time.now + 5` when you ask the question and then make sure they have both a correct answer and a fast-enough answer when they submit their response. Not ideal perhaps, but it could be a workaround. (edit: I see that @SteveTurczyn said basically the same thing while I was typing this. Oh well.)

Comment: Yeah, but @pjd you did explain it better. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use timeout from the standard lib

```
require "timeout"
def gets_timeout( prompt, secs )
  puts
  print prompt + "timeout=#{secs}secs]: "
  Timeout::timeout( secs ) { gets }
rescue Timeout::Error
  puts "*timeout"
  nil  # return nil if timeout
end
```

and running it

```
2.1.5 :010 > test = gets_timeout('hello',3)
hello[timeout=3secs]: *timeout
 => nil 
2.1.5 :011 > test
 => nil 
2.1.5 :012 > test = gets_timeout('hello',3)
hello[timeout=3secs]: test
 => "test\n" 
2.1.5 :013 > test
 => "test\n"
```

i found this example from 
https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/206770

Comment: This is pretty cool but it looks like the user still needs to hit return or else nil will be returned even if some characters are typed?

Comment: @pjd ah i understand, yes it would require the user to hit return to set the string

Comment: Thanks. Ive implemented this, however as mentioned it doesn't get whats currently on the command line.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by @danmanstx helped me to build the working example (I guess it would work on Linux/MacOS):

```
require "timeout"
def gets_timeout( prompt, secs )
  puts
  s = ''
  print prompt + " [timeout=#{secs}secs]: "
  begin
    system("stty raw echo")
    Timeout::timeout( secs ) { loop { s += STDIN.getc } } 
  rescue Timeout::Error
    puts "*timeout"
  ensure
    system("stty -raw echo")
    puts
    puts "We got: [#{s}]"
  end 
end

gets_timeout('hello',3)
```

Additional credits to [Matz](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/2999). Hope it helps.

Comment: cheers @mudasobwa! was about to update my answer with something very similar!

Comment: Very nice! It has some quirks with the way input is accepted (no backspace for corrections, for example), but it seems to do what @robertpulson requested and the details are left to the OP. I am wondering, is there any disadvantage to changing `system("stty raw -echo")` to `system("stty raw echo")` so the user can see what they type?

Comment: @pjd Indeed, `system("stty raw echo")` is way better. Updated. To accept backslashes etc it’s necessary either to dive into `popen` or to somehow involve `readline`, I don’t think it makes sense here.